# How to use com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json in Android Studio

Tags: json, eclipse, google-app-engine, android-studio

I have working code which uses JSON with package shown below.

```
import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONException;
import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject;
```

Code runs in app engine, built under eclipse. And now I'm trying to migrate it to Android Studio. But I can't find out how to refer correct library with it, so I can't compile. My current build.gradle file is shown below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

war.dependsOn appengineEnhance

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:2.1.2'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'javax.jdo:jdo2-api:2.3-eb'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:3.1.3'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }

    enhancer {
        version = "v2"
        api="jdo"
        enhanceOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

There are other libraries I need to add but I want to fix this issue first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Adding next line to build.gradle made successful compile.

```
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.7.4'
```

Now I can go forward to run/debug server side code.